# How to run some action after dropdown's load is complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I need to select a default value after a dropdown is filled with items from my webservice. How can I detect that the load of the dropdown items is complete?

```
    <select id="countriesList"
                    data-url="@Url.Action("GetAllCountries", "Countries", new { Area = "Panel" })"
                    data-bind="options: countries, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: 'Selecione um país', value: selectedCountry">
                </select>
```

And the JS:

```
    $.getJSON($('#countriesList').data('url'), function (data) {
            self.countries(data);
        });
```

Comment: Going to need to know how you're populating your dropdown...

Comment: Can you use the `Success` callback option of the `getJson` method?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
That might occur before knockout binds it though?

Comment: That's the problem, if knockout for some reason take much time to add items from the getJson method, maybe I'll have problems with async execution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own KO binding so you can attach the appropriate callback function: http://jsfiddle.net/RRBzb/

The handler should mimic `ko.bindingHandlers.options` as much as possible, hence the call to `ko.bindingHandlers.options.update`. `ko.bindingHandlers.options` doesn't have an `init` method so there isn't one needed.